# Saving NSDate and NSNumber and/or in the same core data attribute

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, nsdate, nsnumber

It has to be specified while creating the core data model in IB what Kind of attribute it will be, theres choices like String, Date, Integer, Decimal etc.

My question is, how do i store lets say an NSDate in the same attribute, and at some other time, add a new entity but this time with  an NSNumber for that attribute.

In other words, i'd just want an equalent of `id Object` in coredata, where after fetching, i'd check if `[[Object isKindOfClass[NSDate class]]` or an NSNumber.

I've heard of transformable, but i'm not creating customized Objects to be stored. 
Any light on this would be great

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very bad idea. Actually, dates are represented as numbers in SQLite, but Core Data could be using a different kind of store, so you are just making too many assumption of how things are going to work.

It would be much cleaner and easier to specify additional attributes for your entity, a `number` and a `date`. You could then easily check if any of them is `nil` or contains a value. Even introducing a third attribute to tell you if the object has a date or number would be preferable to your setup.

Comment: THe idea was that the entity is basically an "Entry log" so to speak with only two attributes, a timestamp, and value. Timestamp is nsdate obviously, but my idea was the "value" to be just any 'object'. Right now the only requirement was NSNumber or NSDate, if i add an entry of date, the value should record it as date. or if i add an entry for distance, the value would be nsnumber.  Perhaps i could convert nsdate to nsnumber and then store it, I dont want to add one more attribute for just one thing

Comment: Again, I think this is bad design. If you want unstructured "log entries" these should be of type `NSString`. You could always devise your own scheme to distinguish the types (e.g. preceding an int with ' i', a float with 'f', a date with 'd' etc.). It is also easy to write scanners to interpret the data correctly. But why go there if you can store real types?

Answer (score 0):

I have come across this scenario in the current project. If your values contain int, float, boolean you can use NSNumber as attribute and if it contains NSDate then attribute should be as a string in the entity.

Hope this help.

Comment: OUCH!, what if i use transformable as attribute? would that help?

Comment: If transformable is used it will do the job but if you request to fetch the data using NSPredicate then it will create a problem for you.